# What is the advantage to hiring someone with a license?

Tags: contractors

Recently many out of work handymen have shown up at my door asking if they can do any work. One quoted me on some work, at a much lower price than if I looked in the phone book for a licensed contractor, and I was able to get some references from people I know to confirm they are okay. What is the advantage then of hiring someone with a license? Does that help protect me in case something goes wrong during the work?

Comment: Does your village or tribal area issue require permits be pulled or inspections done?  Will a homebuyer want to see proof that permits were pulled?  Do your insurance or mortgage terms say anything about quality of work? How do you feel about illegal aliens? Would you give money up front to a stranger who walks up to your door and talks a good game (if so PM me your street address ;)

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica I treat illegal aliens with  respect and kindness just like  i do all other humans.

Comment: So say we all @Alaskaman. The question is, does "respect and kindness" extend to "conspiracy to violate labor laws"?

Comment: The answer will also vary significantly if the work is being done on your home vs a multifamily/commercial building

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It varies from place to place, but in general, there's a few things you can expect from licensed tradespeople.

- they've shown a commitment to their business, so have a higher probability of being competent.
- they probably have liability insurance (for if they burn your house down) and worker's comp (for if they injure themselves). As a homeowner, you're encouraged to check for proof of both of these things, btw. If an uninsured trade has an accident, it might roll downhill to you or your insurance.
- there's a greater likelihood that they'll be around in the future if a warranty concern comes up.
- depending on jurisdiction, a licensed trade will be able to give you an enforceable contract.
- a licensed trade will be able to pull building permits to ensure that work is done to code.

Comment: There are also consequences for doing unpermitted work. Around here if they catch you doing unpermitted work they will a) yank your occupancy permit so you're in a hotel, b) make you pull a permit to demolish the unpermitted work.  Demolish. No kidding. c) make you pull a permit to re-do the work (or at least make the work complete).  You must provide porta-johns to the workers since your occupancy permit is void. Now with rent control (which means eviction control) you may owe your tenants $$ or alternate space due to their eviction being your fault.

Answer (score 1):

In most US states a *contractor license bond* is required (and in many counties and municipalities when there is no state requirement).

If a contractor should violate the code, the bond provides legal recourse to those harmed by the contractor’s actions (clients and the AHJ), who can file a claim against the bond.