# What kind of license to check for when hiring a builder?

Tags: contractors

This question is a follow-up to [this earlier question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/212872/what-is-the-advantage-to-hiring-someone-with-a-license).

I found someone with a license to do excavating. They have the license that allows them to operate the equipment. I can confirm that in a database for the state. It seems to me kind of like having a driver's license, shows they can operate the vehicle.

Is that the correct kind of license I need to confirm someone has before hiring them?

Or do I need to hire someone with a business license too? Or is the operating license sufficient that my insurance company, mortgage company, wouldn't cause me the issues described in the answer to the linked question?

...note the person does work as an excavator operator, but the company doesn't hire him out, they use him on their own facilities, so he would do this work on the side, outside his normal company.

Comment: This is something that will be highly dependent on jurisdiction: Country, State, possibly even County or City.

Comment: What would be the place to turn to learn the requirements for where I live?

Comment: That depends. Some jurisdictions have great web sites that clearly spell out the requirements. Many don't. But if you list your location then there *might* be someone on this system who can give you some guidance - either specific information or at least where to look.

Comment: Go to your local government office - if they know then they will tell you. Of course if you want to avoid all their permits & fees then that’s  probaly why you are asking here...

Comment: you probably want someone who has liability insurance too. in case they break something expensive that doesn't belong to you while in your employ.

Comment: I think you need to ask if they're a licensed contractor with liability insurance. Be aware that excavating (even with locates) can have bad side effects: gas leaks, water main breaks, fiber outages. All of these have costs associated that you probably don't want to bear.